Debugging permissions in Azure API requests
I'm using Terraform to deploy infrastructure with Azure. Terraform makes some requests that, even with debug logging, don't display the full HTTP request in the logs, so it's tricky to identify the specific request/issue when a request fails.
I have a request that is returning a 403 Forbidden error ("This request is not authorized to perform this operation"). I have a Request ID and a timestamp.
In the Azure console, how can I find the reason that this request failed? In AWS (where I'm coming from), I could use CloudTrail to find the RequestID, and it would show me the full request and which permission is missing.
I tried Activity Log, but searching for this request ID didn't return any results.
Microsoft Support is not an option because they tend to take days to weeks to respond to support requests, and I'm not at liberty to increase our support plan in my company.

You would need to enable the debug logging for the Azure Go SDK during Terraform execution.

That will give me the request ID in Terraform, and the response to the HTTP request from Terraform, but it won't show me any detailed error information that is considered sensitive. That would only be available through the Azure console.
